# How execute testcase using Jenkins Testlink plugin not nunning Java class?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, testlink

Is it possible to execute test cases from Testlink using **Jenkins Testlink plugin** without running java class and invoking top-level maven targets?

Just run Execute Windows batch(run Sikuli scripts) command and generate TAP report.

What should be be added co custom field in this case?

Thanks